# How to get the selected value from a combobox using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Assume I have this html code:

```
<select id="superior" size="1" name="superior">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="c.i.e.m.md.Division_1">DIVISION007</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="c.i.e.m.md.Division_$$_javassist_162_119">MyDivision</option>
    <option value="c.i.e.m.md.Division_121">MyDivision4</option>
    <option value="c.i.e.m.md.Division_122">MyDivision5</option>
</select>
```

So this is a combo box with

```
id=superior
```

and currently value MyDivision is selected.

Using Selenium WebDriver I am trying to get the selected value, but no success.

I tried:

```
String option = this.ebtamTester.firefox.findElement(By.id(superiorId)).getText();
return option;
```

But this returns me all the values in the combobox.

Help please?

Edit:

```
WebElement comboBox = ebtamTester.firefox.findElement(By.id("superior"));
SelectElement selectedValue = new SelectElement(comboBox);
String wantedText = selectedValue.getValue();
```

Comment: What language are you using? java?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is written in C#, but it shouldn't be hard to transition it over to any other language you're using:

```
IWebElement comboBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("superior"));
SelectElement selectedValue = new SelectElement(comboBox);
string wantedText = selectedValue.SelectedOption.Text;
```

SelectElement requires you to use OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI, so at the top, type

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

---

Edit:

I suppose for you, instead of 'driver' you would use

```
IWebElement comboBox = this.ebtamTester.firefox.FindElement(By.Id("superior"));
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying SelectElement consturctor is protected, so I am not allowed to create an instance of it.

Comment: Are you writing in C#, or a different language?  Also, can you edit your main post with the code you're testing out now?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am using JAVA. I edited my first post. new SelectElement() won't work because as I said, the constructor seems protected.

It works when I try: 
    Select selectedValue = new Select(comboBox);
but then, I can't figure out how to get the currently selected text?

Comment: Hello, I made it work like this: 
   WebElement comboBox = ebtamTester.firefox.findElement(By.id("superior"));
            Select selectedValue = new Select(comboBox);
            String wantedText = selectedValue.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
            ebtamTester.logger.logText("Selected value from" + selectBoxName, wantedText);
Thank you..

Comment: selectedValue.SelectedOption.Text; will get you the text of the selected item. Does anyone know how to get the selected value. I want to test that the value is as I expected, not the text as that can change.

Comment: @John Peter Kerr provided answer.

Comment: This will return only single selected option in multiselect combobox.

Answer (score 9):

In Java, the following code should work nicely:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
Select comboBox = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("superior")));
String selectedComboValue = comboBox.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
System.out.println("Selected combo value: " + selectedComboValue);
```

As MyDivision is selected currently, the above code would print "MyDivision"

Answer (score 4):

> selectedValue.SelectedOption.Text; will get you the text of the
>   selected item. Does anyone know how to get the selected value.

To get the selected value use

```
selectedValue.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 3):

To select an option based on the label:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");
```

To get the first selected value:

```
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption()
```

Comment: I tried option.toString() and I got: [[[[Firefox: firefox on UNIX (a88d1b9f-93d8-4140-9693-5a91d59b57f6)] -> id: superior]] -> tag name: option]

Comment: It turns out I need to use .getText. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using XPath in c#

```
  string selectedValue=driver.FindElement(By.Id("superior")).FindElements(By.XPath("./option[@selected]"))[0].Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Based off @Micheal's answer this would be easier to work with following command:

```
string  selectedValue = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Year"))).SelectedOption.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you for improving on [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992495/666583). If you believe your information is better as a new answer than a comment on the existing answer, I recommend to [edit] to ensure your answer is full/complete and does not require reading a different answer and combining it with your new information. Usually, I also leave a comment on that answer to mention that I have posted an improved answer.

Comment: In this case, I believe this is an almost exact duplicate of the existing answer, but with variables inlined onto a single line (albeit with an incorrect string `"Year"` instead of `"superior"`) and less information. I recommend to use comments for this purpose instead of answers.