# Selenium with Java how to deal with combo box

Tags: java, selenium

I want to select a value from a combo box.
I tried this :

```
@Test(enabled = true)
    public void hierarchyLegendArea() throws Exception {
        setUp(Constants.BASE_URL_NAME, "chrome");
        selenium.setSpeed("1500");
        selenium.open(Constants.OPEN_NMA_TEMPLATE_DIR);
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        Thread.sleep(15000);


        String comboBoxId = "//*[@id=\"contentTopBarCombobox\"]/div/div[1]/div[2]";
        String valueInSideComboBoxId ="combo_box_values_cachable";
        selenium.click(comboBoxId); 
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        selenium.click(valueInSideComboBoxId); 
}
```

But that did not worked.
Does anyone know how to select a value from Combo box ?

when i try to add driver variable eclips askes me to declare it

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992001/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-combobox-using-selenium-webdriver-selenium

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("contentTopBarCombobox")));
dropDown.selectByValue("yourValue");
```

Or

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("contentTopBarCombobox")));
dropDown.selectByIndex(1);//choose your value index, for example I choose index 1.
```

You need to import this

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

when you add driver variable in your class.If you using selenium rc (the old one),then you use `selenium.select` instead of `selenium.click`.See

```
selenium.select("yourComboName", "label=yourValue");
```

Comment: what is driver i never used it before ,how i can declare it ?

Comment: @mohammad I prefer Firefox but you can use ie or chrome.

Comment: i edited my question to be more clear

i ment what is the driver variable

Comment: @mohammad driver is org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver and see http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/