# Option value is not getting selected

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select one of the option , my code is pass but at UI no option get selected .

Here is HTML code:

```
<select name="ddlMarketSource" id="ddlMarketSource" class="select fontb selectchange" originalvalue="0" style="width:100px;">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
        <option value="1">Call In</option>
        <option value="2">Fax</option>
        <option value="3">Email</option>
        <option value="4">SMS</option>
        <option value="5">News(Includes EPRC, Cybernet, Newspaper)</option>
        <option value="6">Cold Call</option>
        <option value="7">Search</option>
        <option value="8">Mortgage</option>
        <option value="9">Referral</option>
        <option value="10">N/A</option>

    </select>
```

Here is my statement to select :

```
Select mrkSource = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlMarketSource']")));
        mrkSource.selectByValue("1");
```

Comment: Not sure if you have had a look at [How to get the selected value from a combobox using Selenium WebDriver (Selenium 2)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992001/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-combobox-using-selenium-webdriver-selenium?rq=1), probably might give you an idea to debug this issue.

Comment: It does not help me out ..

Comment: Can you please send some bunch of code before select option ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on my machine.

I have selenium 2.52.0 and Firefox 44.
Try to verify if you are selecting right element. In Chrome you can open console and write

```
$x("//*[@id='ddlMarketSource']")
```

to check your xpath.