# SelectElement object returns null in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with C# and when trying to access and select a value from the dropdown, it's not working.

I tried to debug using breakpoint, when I move cursor on object of SelectElement class object, it's showing null.

But I know everything is correct. whether we use id, name or xpath to locate the element.

I am using chromedriver.

```
SelectElement ss = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("customer")));
```

Comment: What is the exact error? `SelectElement` object can't be `null` after the initialization.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992001/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-a-combobox-using-selenium-webdriver-selenium

Comment: please provide your HTML DOM code. verify that By.Id("customer") has <select> tag or not like <select id='customer'>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to select. If you are trying to select a drop down, then you can use this.

```
var customer = driver.FindElement(By.Id("customer"));
var selectElement = new SelectElement(customer);
selectElement.SelectByValue("customerType");
```

Comment: I did the same but when I trying to debug, when I hover to customer var it's showing null

Comment: Seems like you are not able to find the element by the type, Id. Check if you can find the element by Name or try to use CssSelector if possible